# CentOS Can't get MySQL started when trying to updated from MySQL 5.1 to 5.5

Tags: mysql, centos

I've waded through forum post after forum post. I can't figure this out. I'm using CentOS 6.5, which had MySQL 5.1, but I need 5.5! I've been looking at a lot of posts but the main one I've been using as my go to manual is [this one](http://www.ovaistariq.net/490/a-step-by-step-guide-to-upgrading-to-mysql-5-5/). I've attached a step by step of what I have done and their results. I 
can tell that I have 5.5, but I can't get it to start.

[informatics@aib-bitest ~]$ sudo /sbin/service mysqld start    MySQL Daemon failed to start.    Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]

```
   ## Tried to restart    [root@aib-bitest log]# service mysqld restart    Stopping mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]    MySQL Daemon failed to start.    Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
   ## Tried to update    [root@aib-bitest log]# mysql_upgrade    Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql    Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck    FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
   ## Realized that mysqld is not running    [root@aib-bitest log]# service mysqld status    mysqld is stopped
   ## And then Realized that I couldn't get it running.    [root@aib-bitest log]# service mysqld start    MySQL Daemon failed to start.    Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
   ## Just tested this just because    [root@aib-bitest log]# mysql    ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
   ## Changed access rights    [root@aib-bitest log]# chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql    [root@aib-bitest log]# service mysqld start    MySQL Daemon failed to start.    Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
   ## Restarted Apache    [root@aib-bitest log]# sudo service httpd restart    Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]    Starting httpd:                                            [  OK  ]    [root@aib-bitest log]# service mysqld start    MySQL Daemon failed to start.    Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
   [root@aib-bitest log]# mysql_install_db    Installing MySQL system tables...    150417 10:06:12 [Warning] 'THREAD_CONCURRENCY' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.    150417 10:06:12 [ERROR] Can't find messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys'    150417 10:06:12 [ERROR] Aborting
   150417 10:06:12 [Note]
   Installation of system tables failed!  Examine the logs in    /var/lib/mysql for more information.
   You can try to start the mysqld daemon with:

   shell>     /usr/libexec/mysqld --skip-grant &
   and use the command line tool /usr/bin/mysql    to connect to the mysql database and look at the grant tables:

   shell>     /usr/bin/mysql -u root mysql
   mysql>     show tables
   Try 'mysqld --help' if you have problems with paths.  Using --log    gives you a log in /var/lib/mysql that may be helpful.
   Please consult the MySQL manual section    'Problems running mysql_install_db', and the manual section that    describes problems on your OS.  Another information source are the    MySQL email archives available at http://lists.mysql.com/.
   Please check all of the above before submitting a bug report    at http://bugs.mysql.com/
   #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [root@aib-bitest log]# /usr/libexec/mysqld --skip-grant    150417 10:07:30 [Warning] 'THREAD_CONCURRENCY' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.    150417 10:07:30 [Warning] Using unique option prefix skip-grant instead of skip-grant-tables is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.    150417 10:07:30 [ERROR] Can't find messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys'    150417 10:07:30 [ERROR] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!
   150417 10:07:30 [ERROR] Aborting
   150417 10:07:30 [Note]
   #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [root@aib-bitest log]# /usr/libexec/mysqld --skip-grant-tables    150417 10:08:20 [Warning] 'THREAD_CONCURRENCY' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.    150417 10:08:20 [ERROR] Can't find messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys'    150417 10:08:20 [ERROR] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!
   150417 10:08:20 [ERROR] Aborting
   150417 10:08:20 [Note]
   #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ## Added user = mysql to /etc/my.cnf    [root@aib-bitest log]# nano /etc/my.cnf
   ## Tried this again    [root@aib-bitest log]# /usr/libexec/mysqld --skip-grant-tables    150417 10:35:38 [Warning] 'THREAD_CONCURRENCY' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.    150417 10:35:38 [ERROR] Can't find messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys'    150417 10:35:38 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.    150417 10:35:38 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled    150417 10:35:38 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins    150417 10:35:38 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
   150417 10:35:38 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO    150417 10:35:38 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M    150417 10:35:38 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool    150417 10:35:38 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.    150417 10:35:38  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start    150417 10:35:39 InnoDB: 5.5.40 started; log sequence number 1595675    150417 10:35:39 [ERROR] Aborting
   150417 10:35:39  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...    150417 10:35:40  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675    150417 10:35:40 [Note]
   #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [root@aib-bitest log]# /sbin/service mysqld start    MySQL Daemon failed to start.    Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
```

Comment: thank you for re-formatting that.

Comment: Try running /usr/libexec/mysqld in the console (not via the service command) and see what it prints.  There is often useful information there

Comment: How did you upgrade from 5.1 to 5.5? (RPM or?) Did you follow the upgrade instructions at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html . If you upgraded from the mysql RPM repo then check the package name they call it mysql-community-server. Can you post whats logged in /var/log/messages when you try & start it - the stuff above looks like its console output or something?